# jQuery code not working in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress-theming

```
(function($){
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#city_input").hide();
        alert('working');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I have tried every possible way for running this code. tried with jQuery , var j = noconflict method as well but I don't know why its not working. In browser console its working. though in this code the alert is working it means that the $ is working fine. I don't understand whats going wrong here wasted 3 hrs.

Please not that my JS script is loading in footer it means after wordpress loads jQuery.

Updated:
here is the url : http://goo.gl/5DuWbI
id : test
pw: admin

Comment: i don't know much about working with this way... i can't say its valid but i followed the pattern from an existing js file on the project i am working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this instead without wrapping it in an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression.  Note that you can pass the $ parameter so that everything inside has access to $.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#city_input").hide();
    alert('working');
});
```

**UPDATE:**

As we figured out in chat, this theme is loading the form he's trying to update AFTER the DOM has loaded, so the above code didn't work.

So we came up with a hack like this:

```
function hidecity(){
    jQuery("#city_input").hide();
}
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    setTimeout(hidecity, 1000)
});
```

Comment: and if you run jQuery("#city_input").hide() manually in the js console does that work?

Comment: please check i have pasted the link on that page

Comment: there is no element with the id #city_input.  what exactly are you trying to hide?

Comment: you have to login and then click submit property

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62017/discussion-between-manishie-and-raheel-khan).

Comment: Thanks bro :) for the long support